# Joining edge of International Date Line in world file

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I am currently using world file (http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/mgg/shorelines/gshhs.html) for international boundary information.

Now I have difficulty with map projection that the map ends with International Date Line (IDL).

Can anybody help me with method to join IDL together so that the projection of the map looks like google map where IDL is joined (like this-> http://gyazo.com/cd63a04362b844a728ad5b082a5bf532.png).

Comment: Most online mapping services will allow you to pan across the dateline through some API trickery, but I don't know any desktop GIS applications that allow this.

Comment: Thank you for advice! Since my mother tongue is not English, can you help me think of any keyword to figure this problem such as "join", "180th meridian", "date line", ...?